# ReactJS Responsiveness. How do I make the menu section responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs

All other sections of the react app work fine in all screen widths, but the menu section has an issue.
In the menu section, the navigation dots on the right side don't show until the screen width is 350px. When the screen size is 533px, white space appears on the right side until 651px and then the menu container becomes bigger than the screen width.
When the screen width reaches 837px, the container now starts being smaller than the screen width and white-space appears on the right side of the screen until it gets to 851px. When it's here at 851px, the navigation dots don't show properly until 900px after which white-space starts appearing until 1151px.
When it's here at 1151px, the menu container is bigger than the allocated screen width.
The navigation dots don't appear properly until 1465px.
Everything is well until 17 15px and the white-space on the right reappears.

The cycle continues for even bigger screen widths.

I'm having a really hard time trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Please help.

Here's my SpecialMenu.jsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SubHeading, MenuItem} from '../../components';
import {images, data} from '../../constants';
import {AppWrap} from '../../wrapper';
import './SpecialMenu.css';

const SpecialMenu = () => (
  <div className="app__specialMenu flex__center section__padding">
    <div className="app__specialMenu-title">
      <SubHeading title="Menu that fits your palette" />
      <h1 className="headtext__cormorant">Today's special</h1>
    </div>

    <div className="app__specialMenu-menu">
      <div className="app__specialMenu-menu_wine flex__center">
        <p className="app__specialMenu-menu_heading">Wine & Beer</p>
        <div ClassName="app__specialMenu_menu_items">
          {data.wines.map((wine, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={wine.title  + index} title={wine.title} price={wine.price} tags={wine.tags} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="app__specialMenu-menu_img">
        <img src={images.menu} alt="menu img" />
      </div>

      <div className="app__specialMenu-menu_cocktails flex__center">
        <p className="app__specialMenu-menu_heading">Cocktails</p>
        <div ClassName="app__specialMenu_menu_items">
          {data.cocktails.map((cocktail, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={cocktail.title  + index} title={cocktail.title} price={cocktail.price} tags={cocktail.tags} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>
      <button type="button" className="custom__button">View More</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default AppWrap(SpecialMenu, 'menu');
```

Here's my SpecialMenu.css code:

```
.app__specialMenu{
    flex-direction: column;
    background: var(--color-black);
}

.app__specialMenu-title{
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.app__specialMenu-menu{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.app__specialMenu-menu_heading{
    font-family: var(--font-base);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 58.5px;  
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    color: var(--color-white);
}

.app__specialMenu-menu_wine, .app__specialMenu-menu_cocktails{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.app__specialMenu-menu_img{
    width: 410px;
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

.app__specialMenu-menu_img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.app__specialMenu_menu_items{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2000px){
    .app__specialMenu-menu_img{
        width: 650px;
    }
    .app__specialMenu-menu_img img{
        height: 650px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px){
    .app__specialMenu-menu{
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .app__specialMenu-menu_img{
        margin: 3rem 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
    .app__specialMenu-menu_img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .app__specialMenu-menu_heading{
        font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 48.5px
    }
}
```

Here's my App.css code:

```
.section__padding {
  padding: 4rem 6rem;
}

.flex__center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.app__bg {
  background: url('./assets/bg.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.app__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  min-height: 100vh;
}

.app__wrapper_info {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app__wrapper_img {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.app__wrapper_img-reverse {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.app__wrapper_img img {
  width: 80%;
}

.app__container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.app__navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: var(--color-black);
}

.app__navigation-dot {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    margin: 0.5rem;

    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.app__navigation-dot:hover {
      background-color: var(--color-golden);
}



.custom__button {
  background-color: var(--color-crimson);
    color: var(--color-black);
    font-family: var(--font-base);
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.04em;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom__button:hover{
  background-color: var(--color-golden);
}

.p__cormorant {
  font-family: var(--font-base);
  color: var(--color-white);
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-feature-settings: 'tnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  line-height: 29.9px;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.p__opensans {
  font-family: var(--font-alt);
  color: var(--color-white);
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.headtext__cormorant {
  font-family: var(--font-base);
  color: var(--color-golden);
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 83.2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.spoon__img {
  width: 45px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
  .custom__button,
  .p__cormorant {
    font-size: 37px;
    line-height: 67px;
  }

  .p__opensans {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }

  .headtext__cormorant {
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 210px;
  }

  .spoon__img {
    width: 80px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .app__wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .app__wrapper_img {
    margin: 5rem 0 0 0;
  }

  .app__wrapper_img-reverse {
    margin: 0 0 5rem 0;
  }

  .app__wrapper_img img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .section__padding {
    padding: 4rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .section__padding {
    padding: 4rem 2rem;
  }
  
  .p__cormorant {
    font-size: 21px;
  }

  .p__opensans {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .p__opensans {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .p__cormorant {
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .headtext__cormorant {
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
}
```

And finally here's my index.css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Upright:wght@300;400;500;600;700&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

:root {
  --font-base: 'Cormorant Upright', serif;
  --font-alt: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  
  --color-golden: #DCCA87;
  --color-black: #0C0C0C;
  --color-gray: #545454;
  --color-crimson: #F5EFDB;
  --color-grey: #AAAAAA;
  --color-white: #FFFFFF;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
  color: unset;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slide-bottom {
  -webkit-animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
            transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-bottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
            transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

[image: All other sections work fine except the menu section]

Answer (score 1):

In the App.css file in the app__bg line: `background-size : 100% 100%;` put

Comment: It did not fix it unfortunately.